# Replace changes in first List from second List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list

i have two list and i need first list replace second list, but only changes. I need to save "repository.saveChanges()".

Comment: Why don't you take List2?

Comment: What is the difference between list2 and result

Comment: How does an element in List1 relate to an elemt in list2?

Answer (score 0):

List 2 and result will always be the same. Just use list 2

Comment: _"will always be the same"_ What a bold statement, where do you get that from?

Answer (score 0):

`return` List2 from `repository.saveChanges()`